# Jersey 2.0 and Moxy Internal Server Error But No Server Log

Tags: json, jersey, jax-rs, pojo, moxy

I followed the Jersey 2.0 document (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#json.moxy), modified pom.xml, included jersey-media-moxy artifact, compiled and installed. I could get basic POJO to JSON mapping work for both Produces and Consumes cases.

However, when I tried with some POJO with complex data type as resource return type, I got a lot Status 500 Internal Server Error but without any server log. It is very annoying.  Does anybody know if it is a bug or I missed something in configuration?

By the way, in order to use Moxy mapping for a POJO object, the POJO needs to have a empty parameter constructor.   Are there any other requirements?

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40896460/1751640)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and found this post:

- http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Missing-MOXy-Log-Messages-In-Tomcat-td7580992.html

The author implemented ApplicationEventListener to log the exceptions thrown by Moxy. This is my implementation (needs to be registered in your application):

```
public class ExceptionListener implements ApplicationEventListener {

    @Override
    public void onEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public RequestEventListener onRequest(RequestEvent requestEvent) {
        return new ExceptionRequestEventListener();
    }

    public static class ExceptionRequestEventListener implements RequestEventListener{
        private final Logger logger;

        public ExceptionRequestEventListener(){
            logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(RequestEvent event) {
            switch (event.getType()){
                case ON_EXCEPTION:
                    Throwable t = event.getException();
                    logger.error("Found exception for requestType: "+event.getType(), t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The official [**Jersey**](https://jersey.java.net/) examples that demonstrate how to integrate [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) can be found at the following link:

- https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/json-moxy

Where to find the stacktrace for the internal server error will depend upon your setup, can you provide additional information about yours?

Using the above example if I remove the default constructor from the `org.glassfish.jersey.examples.jsonmoxy.TestBean` class I will get the following exceptions when running `mvn test`.  One of them is good and the other is bad.  I'm going to follow up with the Jersey lead to work out the proper behaviour.

**Bad Exception**

```java
testGet(org.glassfish.jersey.examples.jsonmoxy.JsonResourceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.507 sec  <<< ERROR!
javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:904)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:749)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$500(JerseyInvocation.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:650)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:426)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:646)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:375)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:275)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.examples.jsonmoxy.JsonResourceTest.testGet(JsonResourceTest.java:76)
```

**Good Exception**

```java
roundTripTest(org.glassfish.jersey.examples.jsonmoxy.JsonResourceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.048 sec  <<< ERROR!
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException.factoryMethodOrConstructorRequired(JAXBException.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.finalizeProperties(AnnotationsProcessor.java:896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processClassesAndProperties(AnnotationsProcessor.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.Generator.<init>(Generator.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1017)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.getJAXBContext(MOXyJsonProvider.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.writeTo(MOXyJsonProvider.java:787)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:194)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter.aroundWriteTo(LoggingFilter.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1005)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:430)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:650)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:426)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:646)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:402)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.examples.jsonmoxy.JsonResourceTest.roundTripTest(JsonResourceTest.java:84)
```

---

**UPDATE**

Starting with EclipseLink 2.5.1 you can use `MOXyJsonProvider` standalone to test your model.

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider;

public class Demo {

    private List<Foo> foos;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MOXyJsonProvider moxyJsonProvider = new MOXyJsonProvider();

        Field field = Demo.class.getDeclaredField("foos");

        List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>(1);
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setBar("Hello World");
        foos.add(foo);

        moxyJsonProvider.writeTo(foos, field.getType(), field.getGenericType(), null, null, null, System.out);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I deployed my app as Servlet to Jetty server by following this document (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html#server-jdk).  I also tried the same servlet with Tomcat server.  Neither server has server log in stdout or server log files when giving back 500 Internal Server error.

Comment: Jersey recently has a bug tracking this missing log issue:  https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2000